# Why is my external monitor going black repeatedly every time I play a game

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a 4 year old laptop with an Intel graphics card and a Quadro P600 graphics card. The laptop is hooked to an external monitor - a Dell U3821DW at a resolution of 3840x1600. I only run the monitor - the laptop lid stays closed. The laptop is connected to a dock which is connected to the monitor. I've never had a problem with this configuration.

Recently, I have begun playing WoW (in prep for Dragonflight). This is the first time I've played on this laptop. I am running WoW full screen (but windowed does not fix the issue). When I fire up WoW, I can play for a bit fine. Then, after about 10 minutes (almost to a T), the monitor starts flickering heavily. Not just screen flicker but black out/back in like it's trying to reset or something.

Then, after doing this for some amount of time, it stops. And once it stops it won't do it again as long as I keep WoW running.

I cannot figure out why this is happening in the first place and have spent a great deal of time researching and I'm out of ideas. All drivers are up-to-date (graphics or otherwise). Running Windows 11 fully patched. No other apps are running in the foreground when this happens (e.g. browser or anything else).

What might be going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: I assume you are running [these](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/192043/en-us/) drivers from Nvidia since anything directly from the OEM wouldn’t have support Windows 11

Comment: [Make sure you have enabled DX11 Legacy and such a low class GPU](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/t/directx-11-legacy/121429/4) official stance from blizzard would be that the GPU isn’t actually supported. Your issue most certainly is that your hardware is overheating.

Comment: Unlikely, and depends on the way the game is made, but full-screen games sometimes "lose context" when notifications or other windows attempt to display, and the game needs to refresh the GPU context (restart the game's display subsystem, similar to changing resolution). Used to be more likely years ago and with DX9. Could be a e.g. conhost scheduled task etc

Comment: Yes, I am using the official drivers.

I did switch to DX11 instead of 12, that didn't seem to make a difference.

To the overheating, it happens 10 minutes in, flickers (hard) for a bit, then stops and works fine the rest of the time. So, there may be heat, but this doesn't seem to be an issue.

Someone (IRL) did suggest mismatching refresh rates or something, but I didn't quite understand.

Comment: Overheating is ALWAYS an issue!

Comment: True, but I would expect that the screen continues to flicker. But it doesn't. It flickers about 20 - 100 times over 5 minutes and then is fine for the rest of (many hours) of gaming. Wouldn't heat cause it to have a kind of permanent issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue. I'm not sure why it was causing the issue (would love more information about that), but at least the problem is fixed.

I noticed that the Nvidia Control Panel said that the settings for graphics was now managed by Windows 11. So, I dug deeper into the Windows 11 settings. (System > Display > Advanced Display) When I switched over to my external monitor (Display 2: DELL U3821DW), I noticed that there was an option that said "Choose Refresh Rate" and the rate of 59.93 Hz was selected. The other options were: 29.97, 30, and 59.99. So, on a whim, I switched it to 59.99 Hz and...no more flickering or issues.

Everything appears to be working well otherwise. I switched WoW back to DirectX 12.

If anyone has further detail of why this fixed my problem (or if I really should not have done that), additional explanation would be much appreciated. Wanted to share in case anyone else ran across this issue!